# Spring serialization error for AmazonS3 client

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, spring-security

I've got a weird problem which I can't really understand.

I've a got a code to upload a file to AWS S3 bucket using AmazonS3 client. I've got a try-catch block where I catch any exception and in catch block I throw my defined exception which is handled by controller method @ExceptionHandler and should return thymeleaf template errorUpload.html.

```
@Service
public class UploadService {
    private final AmazonS3 amazonS3;
    private final String bucketName;

    public UploadService(AmazonS3 amazonS3, @Value("${aws.bucketName}") String bucketName) {
        this.amazonS3 = amazonS3;
        this.bucketName = bucketName;
    }

    public void manualUpload(MultipartFile file) {
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentType(file.getContentType());
        metadata.setContentLength(file.getSize());

        try {
            amazonS3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, file.getName(), file.getInputStream(), metadata));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UploadException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Exception handler:

```
@ExceptionHandler({UploadException.class})
public String uploadError() {
    return "errorPages/errorUpload";
}
```

When I simply throw exception in manualUpload method without any logic it works fine. But when AmazonS3 object is used and it throws exception then logic goes to ExceptionHandler but it thorws below error:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object] to type [byte[]] for value 'com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client@4b0ac28c'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:192) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.serialize(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:623) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.access$400(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:133) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository$1.setValues(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:487) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$batchUpdate$4(JdbcTemplate.java:1042) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:691) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:1034) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.insertSessionAttributes(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:479) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.access$1200(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:133) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository$JdbcSession.lambda$save$10(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:854) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.lambda$executeWithoutResult$0(TransactionOperations.java:68) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.executeWithoutResult(TransactionOperations.java:67) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository$JdbcSession.save(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:836) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository$JdbcSession.access$200(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:665) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.save(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:422) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.save(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:133) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:226) ~[spring-session-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:193) ~[spring-session-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:145) ~[spring-session-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82) ~[spring-session-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:352) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:64) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:33) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterAdapter.convert(GenericConversionService.java:386) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.java:43) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.Serializer.serializeToByteArray(Serializer.java:56) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:60) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

I think it might be related with storing SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT in spring_session_attributes table so because AmazonS3 is not serialiazed it throws that error. Any ideas how this can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.
Any not serializable object cannot be created as a bean and used because in this case when this particular bean is going to be stored in in SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT the serialization exception occurs.
So the solution for that is simply not creating Bean but instead just create object using "new" keyword in place when we want to use it.

```
@Service
public class UploadService {
    private final String bucketName;
    private final S3Client s3Client;

    public UploadService(@Value("${aws.bucketName}") String bucketName,
                         @Value("${aws.accessKey}") String awsAccessKey,
                         @Value("${aws.secretKey}") String awsSecretKey) {
        this.s3Client = S3Client.builder()
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey)))
                .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                .build();
        this.bucketName = bucketName;
    }

    public void manualUpload(MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            s3Client.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).key(file.getName()).build(),
                    RequestBody.fromBytes(file.getBytes()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UploadException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I am in fact using the builder in my case and didn't notice that you weren't. Still, it is nice to know that you found the problem.

Comment: @JoãoDias Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is indeed strange. It seems to me that you are using the old version of AWS SDK for Java (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3), so I would suggest you updating it to the new version (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/s3) and check if the issue persists.

For more and detailed information check AWS documentation on how to migrate https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/migration.html.

Comment: I've replaced upload logic with the new version of aws sdk and it's the same problem.
`Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client`